# Hover menu implementation in CSS hide Menu panel after onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, dom-events

I'm creating a menu which will be active on hovering on a menu item in the menu bar. Everything went as expected but while clicking on an item in the menu panel this menu panel is not hiding. How to make this menu panel hide after `onclick` event has fired.

NB: I'm using pure CSS tricks to hide/show menu panel on hover. Like changing the display attribute to none/block.
Also there is no navigation to new page/ the page won't get redrawn after clicking the menu item. The intention of the menu item is just to add some content to the existing page.
Please let me know if any additional info is required

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: I'm guessing you are showing the submenu with `:visited` or possibly `:focused` states. Please share your code to reproduce and inspect the problem properly. Ideally create a jsFiddle demo or share a link to live site.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `:active` pseudo-selector.
The trouble lies in how to relate the item with the panel.

For example if the panel is inside the item that will be clicked:

```
#item:active #panel{
  display:none;
}
```